# How would I make multiple 'players' and save them using pickle and classes

Tags: python, pickle

Just to clarify, I am quite new to python. I have got this code

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.base_defence = 0
        self.helm = "Worn Helmet"
        self.chest = "Worn Shirt"
        self.pants = "Worn Pants"
        self.boots = "Worn Boots"
        self.weap = "None"
        self.wbow = "None"
        self.gold = 1000 
        self.base_strength = 10 
        self.maxmana = 100
        self.mana = self.maxmana
        self.level = 1
        self.exp = 0
        self.maxexp = 100
        self.maxhealth = 100
        self.health = self.maxhealth
        self.inventory = [
                          "Worn Shirt", 
                          "Worn Pants", 
                          "Worn Boots",
                          "Worn Helmet"
                          ]
```

And I want to make a function to not only create a new player, but pickle the data of the player so i can load it later.
I have been recommended a tuple, but from what I have seen, every time I want a new player I would have to write a line of code, which is inefficient if I want to have multiple players.

How would i do this?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to store these details in a database instead of pickling the object. Look at options such as SQLite3 or MySQL, here are some links.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp